# How can I use avformat_open_input function (ffmpeg)

Tags: c++, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I have bought a `HD HDMI to UVC` device which has HDMI video source input and UVC for video output [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NI9ORGI).
I connect it from laptop A (input source HDMI) to laptop B (output USB).
I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 desktop on Laptop B and Win 8.1 on Laptop A.
B also have ffmpeg, opencv and sdl library installed.
My target is to capture video and audio from A via `HD HDMI to UVC` on B.
So I have decided to use libav of `ffmpeg`.
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463337/using-ffmpeg-to-capture-frames-from-webcam-and-audio-from-micro-and-saving-to-fi) and used `avformat_open_input` function but this function returned error.
I thought that the error was occurred because the second parameter of `avformat_open_input` (`const char * url`) was invalid.
I know that the `url` should be like `video:video device name:audio:audio card name`.
How can I indicate the device names?

Here's the result of `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` command in terminal.

```
HD WebCam (usb-0000:02:03.0-1):   
    /dev/video0
HD TV CAM (usb-0000:03:00.0-2.1):   
    /dev/video1
```

And the result of `arecord -l` in terminal.

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****  
card 0: AudioPCI [Ensoniq AudioPCI], device 0: ES1371/1 [ES1371 DAC2/ADC]  
Subdevices: 1/1  
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0    
card 1: CAM [HD TV CAM], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]    
Subdevices: 1/1  
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, did you managed to open both (audio and video) streams with avformat_open_input function? I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution to access a USB webcam using FFmpeg's API.

```
int CaptureCam() 
  {

  avdevice_register_all(); /* for device & add libavdevice/avdevice.h headerfile*/
  avcodec_register_all();
  av_register_all();

  char *dev_name = "/dev/video0"; // here mine is video0 , it may vary.
  AVInputFormat *inputFormat =av_find_input_format("v4l2");
  AVDictionary *options = NULL;
  av_dict_set(&options, "framerate", "20", 0);

  AVFormatContext *pAVFormatContext = NULL; 

    // check video source
  if(avformat_open_input(&pAVFormatContext, dev_name, inputFormat, NULL) != 0)
  {
   cout<<"\nOops, could'nt open video source\n\n";
   return -1;
  }
  else
  {
   cout<<"\n Success !";
  }

  } // end function
```

Comment: Hi, your answer works good, but only for video stream. I'm trying to open both audio and video, and it is not working with v4l2 format. In windows it is posible to use dshow with url specified in format "video=<camera_name>:audio=<microphone_name>", but I cannot find solution to do it in linux