# Capturing Webcam via OpenCV in Java. FPS @ 30 fps instead of 60

Tags: java, javafx, webcam, opencv3.0, capture

first of all, sorry for my english. it´s a bit rusty...

i´m trying to solve a problem for a couple of days with opencv3.0 in combination with Java and JavaFX.

I tried to capture a Webcam videostream from a logitech c922 which can capture  60 fps with a Resolution of 720p.

here is snippet...

```
public void startCapture(ImageView realView, int frameWidth, int frameHeight){

    moveCoordSystemToCenter(frameWidth/2, frameHeight/2);  

    if (!this.capture.isOpened()){
        capture.open(cameraNo); 

        int fourcc = VideoWriter.fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G');
        capture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, fourcc);   

        capture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1280);
        capture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,720);

            TimerTask frameGrabber = new TimerTask(){
                public void run(){

                    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    Image tmp =  grabFrame();

                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){   
                        int Counter = 1;
                        long res = 0;

                        public void run(){
                                realView.setImage(tmp);
                                res = res + System.currentTimeMillis()-time;
                                System.out.println("Fps = " + 1000 / (res/Counter)) ;
                                Counter++;
                        }
                    });
                }
            };      
                            this.timer = new Timer();       
                            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(frameGrabber, 0, 1); // has no effect
                            System.out.println("task");
    }
    else
    {
        if (this.timer != null){
            this.timer.cancel();
            this.timer = null;
        }
    this.capture.release();
    }       
}

private Image grabFrame() {

    Image imageToShow = null;
    Mat frame = new Mat();

    if ( this.capture.isOpened()){
            try
            {

                this.capture.read(frame);
                if (!frame.empty()){
                    imageToShow = mat2Image(frame);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
            }
    }
    return imageToShow; 
}

private Image mat2Image (Mat frame){
    MatOfByte buffer = new MatOfByte();
    Imgcodecs.imencode(".bmp",frame, buffer);
    return new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toArray()));
}
```

I tried some stuff like capture(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FPS,60) which has an effect for Settings under 30 fps.

I tried to record a stream from the cam in Windows10 Cam app which works fine, so it can´t be a problem with lumination or somethink in this direction.

Got someone any idea???!

Greetz

Comment: OpenCV cannot read MJPEG data from camera. Try FFMPEG for reading compressed video stream.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Do you mean to change these lines?   int fourcc = VideoWriter.fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G');
        capture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, fourcc);     How could i set entry codec? what is the native opencv short to 4 letters?

Comment: No I mean use another software with another API to capture compressed video stream from camera. Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463337/using-ffmpeg-to-capture-frames-from-webcam-and-audio-from-micro-and-saving-to-fi   JNI wrapper for ffmeg may be founded here https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets